# Is it possible to use applicationcontext for getting multiple dao beans defined in souce.xml file?

Tags: spring-mvc

I created a mvc spring project and used dao class using applicationcontext that was defined in source.xml file.

Now I'm applying transaction to a newly created daoclass and defined it in source.xml.

Can I use applicationcontext for calling both these dao classes in main?  If so, then how do I do this?

Comment: Saying "thanks" and such is frowned upon; the preference is to make the questions short and to the point. The question looks like it could use some more improvement, but I don't know enough about the subject matter to do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes This is possible, 2 months ago i was a newbie in spring mvc. now i can answer this question which will help other newbies.

Step 1: Make a master/main class which contains Application Context
Step 2: Declare each dao in resource.xml and add their dependence either on any other class or on dataSource.
Step 3: Then in each adapter class (class between dao and controller layer) you can import this main Application Context and use it to call the multiple dao.

Here is the sample code:

// Main application Context code

```
public class MainAdaptor 
{
    static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("MySQL_DataSource.xml");   
}
```

//sample Code for using main context you can use this in multiple classes

```
public class OrderProcessingAdapter {

    static SalesDaoImpl     salesDaoImpl    = (SalesDaoImpl)    MainAdaptor.context.getBean("SalesDaoImpl");
    static LocalityDaoImpl  localityDaoImpl = (LocalityDaoImpl) MainAdaptor.context.getBean("LocalityDaoImpl");
    static StaffDaoImpl     staffDaoImpl    = (StaffDaoImpl)    MainAdaptor.context.getBean("StaffDaoImpl");
    static ShippingInfoDaoImpl shippingInfoDaoImpl = (ShippingInfoDaoImpl)MainAdaptor.context.getBean("ShippingInfoDaoImpl");
    }
```

// resource.xml declaration sample

```
<!-- Initialization for data source -->
 <bean id="dataSource" class= "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grocery"></property>
      <property name="username" value="newuser"></property>
      <property name="password" value="kmsg"></property>
   </bean>

    <bean id="CarDetailsDaoImpl" class="org.kmsg.dao.daoImpl.CarDetailsDaoImpl">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     </bean>

     <bean id="CarTypeDaoImpl" class="org.kmsg.dao.daoImpl.CarTypeDaoImpl">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean> 

   <bean id="CategoriesDaoImpl" class="org.kmsg.dao.daoImpl.CategoriesDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

//Enjoy it!

Leave comment if any help needed.
Thanks